# Creating sign-post questions

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I came across a problem I couldn't quickly solve myself (stress related, my search skills were turned off). I copy and pasted the message into the Search bar of SU, and could not find any results in the first page. I was about to create a new question with the error message as the title, then I saw questions that had answers. I clicked the fourth one, which had the solution to my problem.

I don't want to create unnecessary noise on the site, but I also think that the exact error message should have been included, or at least point to it. Is there a problem with me creating a question, and closing it as a duplicate so there is a signpost to the solution?

Comment: Can't this be solved by editing existing questions to state the problem more clearly? Search has been improved a lot recently.

Comment: In this instance, I guess it could... That makes more sense... I'll have to turn my brain back on before I post again